# Is $\|A\|=\lim_{n\to\infty}|tr A^n|^{1/n}$ a norm?

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis

For matrix A, define
$$\|A\|=\lim_{n\to\infty}|\operatorname{tr}{(A^n)}|^{1/n}.$$
Is this a norm defined on some specific subspace of $Gl(d,\mathbb{R})$? Does it have a name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, of course it is not a norm. The limit doesn't always exist, and even then it can be zero for nonzero $A$.

But if you use instead the absolute value of $A$, $|A|=(A^*A)^{1/2}$, then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\,\text{Tr}(|A|^n)^{1/n}
$$
exists and it agrees with the spectral norm of $A$.

**Edit:** here is a proof of the aforementioned fact. Writing $s_1,\ldots,s_k$ for the singular values of $A$, we have $\text{Tr}(|A|^n)^{1/n}=(s_1^n+\cdots s_k^n)^{1/n}$, and
$$
\|A\|_{sp}=s_1\leq(s_1^n+\cdots s_k^n)^{1/n}\leq (k\,s_1^n)^{1/n}=k^{1/n}\,s_1.
$$
So
$$
s_1\leq\liminf_{n\to\infty}\text{Tr}(|A|^n)^{1/n}\leq\limsup_{n\to\infty}\text{Tr}(|A|^n)^{1/n}\leq\,s_1\,\limsup_{n\to\infty}k^{1/n}=s_1.
$$
Thus the limit exists and agrees with $s_1$.